# TMDB API - using jQuery to get film genres and images

Tags: jquery, api

I've got basic HTML and jQuery code which shows films currently playing (will add CSS later), but I also want to add each film's genre and image. I'm not sure how to do this. Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Test</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var api_key = 'mysecretapikey';

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=' + api_key,

        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'testing'
      }).error(function() {
        console.log('error')
      }).done(function(response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
          $('#search_results').append('<li>' + response.results[i].title + '</li>');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <h2>Now Playing</h2>


  <p id="error"></p>
  <ul id="search_results"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you would use https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/genres/get-movie-list for genres and https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-images for images. Hope that this helps out.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just not sure how to call more than one URL, any advice appreciated.